# Evento "Click" no funciona al eliminar y crear un elemento con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

En este pequeño ejemplo, deseo que al presionar el botón "Agregar Archivo" se muestre el `input` de tipo file, y que al presionar luego al botón de "Eliminar INPUT File", éste se elimine y muestre el HTML que tenía en un comienzo.

Funciona bien la primera vez, pero luego de eso no, ya que requiero que el compartamiento sea continuo.

Gracias de antemano.

```js
document.getElementById("act_agregar_archivo").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("eliminar").disabled = false;

        document.getElementById("act_add_documento").remove();  

        const input_file = document.createElement("input");

        input_file.setAttribute("type", "file");
        input_file.setAttribute("id", "act_documento");

        const content = document.getElementById("doc");
        content.appendChild(input_file);
};

document.getElementById("eliminar").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("eliminar").disabled = true;
    
    if (document.getElementById("act_documento")) {
            document.getElementById("act_documento").remove();

            const mostrar_documento = "<div id='act_add_documento'><span>Texto</span> <button id='act_agregar_archivo'>Agregar archivo</button></div>";


            document.getElementById("label").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", mostrar_documento);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="doc" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
    <label id="label" style="display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px">Archivo</label>
    <div id="act_add_documento">
        <span>Texto</span>
        <button id="act_agregar_archivo">Agregar archivo</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="eliminar" disabled>Eliminar INPUT File</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres es mostrar y ocultar elementos, fácilmente puedes hacerlo con `display: none` para ocultar y `display: block` para mostrar, así:

```js
document.getElementById("act_agregar_archivo").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("eliminar").disabled = false;

  this.parentElement.style.display = "none";

  const input_file = document.createElement("input");

  input_file.setAttribute("type", "file");
  input_file.setAttribute("id", "act_documento");

  const content = document.getElementById("doc");
  content.appendChild(input_file);
};

document.getElementById("eliminar").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("eliminar").disabled = true;

  if (document.getElementById("act_documento")) {
    document.getElementById("act_documento").remove();

    document.getElementById("act_add_documento").style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="doc" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
  <label id="label" style="display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px">Archivo</label>
  <div id="act_add_documento">
    <span>Texto</span> 
    <button id="act_agregar_archivo">Agregar archivo</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="eliminar" disabled>Eliminar INPUT File</button>
```